# Prove that an operator (with heat kernel) maps the space of $C^1$ functions with bounded derivatives to itself

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $K$ be the [*heat kernel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel).

- Does the operator 
  $$g \mapsto\int_0^T\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} K(t-\xi,x-\zeta) \ \  f(\xi,\zeta,g(\xi,\zeta),\nabla g(\xi,\zeta)) \, d\xi \, d\zeta$$
  map the space of $C^1([0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^N)$ (for any $T>0$) functions bounded and with bounded derivatives to itself if $f: [0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ is sufficiently well-behaved (for instance $C^1$)?
- Does it do the same for the space of $C^2$ or $C^\infty$ functions with bounded derivatives?

---

Here $\nabla$ is used to denote the gradient with respect to the space variable $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: A small space before dx in f(x) dx, thus $f(x)\,dx,$ is used by the more fastidious typographers if I'm not mistaken, and there seem to be obvious advantages to ease of reading. I edited the posting accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I think I understand the domain of $f$, but it is not what you've written.

Comment: @uniquesolution Why not?

Comment: Because the gradient of $g$ is not in $R^N$.

Comment: @uniquesolution I mean the gradient in the space variable $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: you should try to match what you write and what you mean. After all, this is mathematics.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I might add that sticklers for mathematical typography also use an upright "d" for differentials.

Comment: @MichaelLee : You're quite mistaken about that. That appears to be conventional among physicists and not among mathematicians. The production editors at the _Pacific Journal of Mathematics_ are extremely fastidious, so look at this: http://msp.org/pjm/2008/236-1/pjm-v236-n1-pC1-s.pdf $\qquad$

Comment: I know nothing about the editing standards of the _Pacific Journal of Mathematics_, but I might mention for you to check [ISO 80000-2:2009](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~jwilson/files/mathsigns.pdf). Page 23 of that PDF. At the very least, this is standard across the sciences and technology fields.

Comment: @Jay: What do we know, if anything, about the boundedness of $f$?

Comment: @AlexM. We could as well assume it bounded, but does that influence the result?

Comment: @Jay: You should attempt to make your questions as clear as possible from the very beginning: inside $f$, do $g$ and $\nabla g$ depend on $(t,x)$ or on $(\xi, \zeta)$? Please edit your post to include the correct arguments.

Comment: @AlexM. Thanks for pointing out the possible confusion: I've included the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

For my typing convenience allow me to drop the Greek letters. For a suitable class of functions $f$ and for $g$ of class $C^k$ with all derivatives bounded, you are asking whether

$$\tilde g (t,x) = \int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} K(t-u, x-y) f \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big) \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d u $$

is of class $C^k$ with all the derivatives bounded.

As you are going to see, it turns out that this has nothing to do with $K$ being the heat kernel, the problem can be posed for much more general integral kernels.

Notice that

$$\partial _t \big( K(t-u, x-y) \big) = (D_1 K) (t-u, x-y) = - \partial _u \big( K(t-u, x-y) \big)$$

and

$$\partial _{x_i} \big( K(t-u, x-y) \big) = (D_2 K) (t-u, x-y) \frac {\partial (x-y)} {\partial x_i} = \\
- (D_2 K) (t-u, x-y) \frac {\partial (x-y)} {\partial y_i} = - \partial _{y_i} \big( K(t-u, x-y) \big)$$

where $D_1 K$ and $D_2 K$ are the derivatives of $K$ with respect to the 1st, respectively the 2nd, argument ($D_2 K$ is a vector that gets paired with the vector $\dfrac {\partial (x-y)} {\partial x_i}$ in the natural way).

Using Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem we may slip all the derivatives inside the integral, and then integration by parts gives:

$$(\partial _t \tilde g) (t,x) = \int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} \partial _t K(t-u, x-y) f \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big) \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d u  = \\
- \int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} \partial _u K(t-u, x-y) f \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big) \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d u = \\
\int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} K(t-u, x-y) \partial _u f \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big) \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d u = \\
\int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} K(t-u, x-y) (D_1 f) \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big) \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d u + \\
\int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} K(t-u, x-y) (D_3 f) \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big) \frac {\partial g} {\partial u} (u,y) \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d u + \\
\int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} K(t-u, x-y) (D_4 f) \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big) \frac {\partial (\nabla g)} {\partial u} (u,y) \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d u .$$

If $f$ is $C^1$ with the derivatives bounded (say, by some $M>0$), then the first term in the sum of three integrals above is bounded by

$$0 \le \left| \int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} K(t-u, x-y) (D_1 f) \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big) \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d u \right| \le \\
\int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} \left| K(t-u, x-y) (D_1 f) \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big)  \right| \Bbb d y \Bbb d u = \\
\int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} K(t-u, x-y) \left| (D_1 f) \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big)  \right| \Bbb d y \Bbb d u \le
M \int \limits _0 ^T \int \limits _{\Bbb R^n} K(t-u, x-y) \ \Bbb d y \Bbb d u $$

which is finite.

A similar computation can be done for the other two terms, too, but for them you'll also have to use the boundedness of the derivatives of $g$.

We conclude that $\partial _t \tilde g$ is bounded with respect to both $t$ and $x$.

A similar computation can be done for $\partial _{x_i} \tilde g$ - the same idea, the same steps, just longer to write because now $x$ is a vector. You will get boundedness for $\partial _{x_i} \tilde g$ too.

When $K$ is the heat kernel, the condition of boundedness on $f$ may be relaxed, imposing instead that the map $y \mapsto (D_i f) \big( u, y, g(u,y), (\nabla g) (u,y) \big)$ be in some $L^{p_i} (\Bbb R^n)$ uniformly with respect to $u$ (because the heat kernel is in $L^q (\Bbb R^n)$ for every $q \in [1, \infty]$ it may be paired with functions from any $L^p$ to get finite results).

The same reasoning works for derivatives of arbitrary order: if $f$ and $g$ are of class $C^k$ with bounded derivatives, so will be $\tilde g$. You may do it inductively, it is just long to write. Again, when $K$ is the heat kernel, the condition on $f$ may be relaxed, for instance by imposing that its composition with $g$ and $\nabla g$ belong to some Sobolev space $W^{k,p} (\Bbb R^n)$ - again, you only want its product with $K$ to be integrable on $\Bbb R^n$. The integral on $[0,T]$ does not bother you because this is a compact space so working with it is much easier. In particular, when $K$ is of class $C^k$ (not necessarily the heat kernel) then it is known that convoluting with it will again be of class $C^k$, so in particular continuous, so in particular bounded with respect to $t \in [0,T]$, so in particular integrable with respect to $t \in [0,T]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So we can conclude that $\tilde{g}$ both *bounded* and *with bounded derivatives*, right?

Comment: @Jay: Yes. To simplify things for you, if $f$ and $g$ are of class $C^k$ with bounded derivatives, so will be $\tilde g$.